# how to append user input to Http get request in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9, http-get

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read through my question.

I'm upgrading an old project from Laravel 8 to Laravel 9

in laravel 8 i was able to append user input to a get request like this :

```
public function fetch(Request $request)
    {
        $userInput = $request->input();

        $response = Http::withHeaders(
            [
                "x-rapidapi-host"=> "some.api",
                "x-rapidapi-key"=> "**************",
            ]
        )->get("https://some.api.com",$userInput);

        $data = json_decode($response,true);

        return view('view',compact('data'));
    }
```

but when i try to do the same process in Laravel 9 i'm getting an error:

> Invalid request

**edit:** (using dd() to show more error details about the response I'm getting)

```
array:4 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\apiController.php:29
  "searchType" => "Title"
  "expression" => null
  "results" => []
  "errorMessage" => "Invalid request. See more information at https://theapiI'mUsing.com/api#/{lang?}/API/Search/{expression}  - Search APIs: Search, SearchTitle, SearchName, SearchEpisod ▶"
]
```

I'm not able to send the data to the controller i guess? expression is showing null

although I was able to accomplish my goal using the same code in laravel 8

I have tried to append the input like this:

```
        $response = Http::get("https://some.api.com/apiKey", [
            'input' => $userInput,
        ]);
```

but also got the same error!

> Invalid request

**edit**:

I have Also tried to concatenate the url with the user input

but got this error:

> Array to string conversion

What is the proper way to append user input to a get request in Laravel 9?

Comment: not sure about the issue but try `$userInput = $request->input()->toArray();`

Comment: @itachi thank you, but didn't help, the userInput should be converted from array to string. not able to find the proper way though. and not knowing why in laravel 9 the Request is fetching user input as an array not a string !

Comment: because as per docs, **You may call the input method without any arguments in order to retrieve all of the input values as an associative array:** it wil always return an array.

Comment: @itachi **i have edited my question** dear sir to add more details about the error i'm facing, **I've used dd() to see what response i'm getting**, what do you recommend sir?.